# how can i use rails 3 router out of rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, router

I use a vps, i will cache all the pages use page cache. After do that, i think i don't need load all rails stuff in memory, just router parse will work for me. Does any one know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are serving static pages in Rails, you can just place them in 'public/' directory, that way you would not use any routes. However if you serve them in views, you would need to interact with your routes, since views is entirely separated it needs to talk to routes to get into a controller action. (views -> routes -> controller_action)